# Setting ChildrenRect width for grid in qml?

Tags: qml

I need to know how to set the ChildrenRect height and width for a grid element??

```
 Grid {
             id: grid1
             anchors.fill: parent
             rows: 10
             columns: 10


             childrenRect.height: background.height/10
             childrenRect.width: background.width/10

         }
```

it says its a read-only element that cannot be changed when i try to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't set them. The `childrenRect` properties are calculated from the item's children. The only way to affect them is by setting the children's dimensions. There's no way to set them yourself.